# Bragging about previous funded PhD position to acquire another?

Tags: phd, application

I am in the process of leaving a funded PhD position and apply elsewhere. There was a lot of competition for the position, and the benefits were good (being employed by the university), but things didn't work out (mainly I want to pursue research that is not being done in my first university).

Could it be useful to brag about how I got a competetive PhD position in my application to other places? My first university is not famous, but I did come in the top 5% of over hundred applicants.

Comment: How do you prove you did come in the **top 5%** of over hundred applicants after you brag about it?

Comment: @scaaahu I can imagine programs publishing this sort of info.

Comment: @xLeitix I did see that kind of published info before. But, those published reports only include info like average or highest GPA, GRE scores of applicants. I never saw student names published, have you?

Comment: @scaaahu I was more thinking that in an acceptance letter, programmes may tell the student that they accepted only X% of applications, similarly to what many conferences do. If you have been accepted, it is fair to say that you were among the top X% of applications.

Comment: I am not sure that leaving a competitive PHD program to go to another, is something to brag about

Answer (score 8):

This is just an opinion:

You will need to be very clear why you left, and you cannot leave room for the suggestion that it was just because things got a bit uninteresting. The way you have described it in your question leaves me with that presumption, and on that basis I would feel uncomfortable with working with you on a fixed term (or fixed goal) project such as a PhD.

*i.e.*, the obvious question in the mind of the reader of your CV will be, "How do I know you won't disappear on me as soon as things get a bit boring or difficult?"

Frankly, I think you have more to lose than you have to gain by discussing it.

Answer (score 0):

Research interests can sharpen or crystallise during a PhD, so it is definitively possible to realign interest. However, the case for a switch needs to be absolutely compelling.

Usually supervisors avoid taking on someone who started a PhD somewhere else, unless the case is very strong - and coming out on the top 5% is, at that stage, not anymore a very strong reason to accept a student; the main reason has now become "is the student really interested in doing what I am interested in"?